# How do I use a custom query in the model yii2 framework

Tags: yii2

How do I use a custom query in a model using the yii2 framework? I am trying but errors occurs.

I am a beginner in Yii2 Framework.

Here is my login model:

```
public function getUser($id)
{
    $return = User::findBySQL("Select * from User where userType = 'AHP' and userid = '$id';");
    return($return['AHPName']);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with `ActiveQuery`:

```
public function getUser($id)
{
  $data = User::find()->where(['userType' => 'AHP', 'userid' => $id])->one();
  return $data['AHPName'];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**[findOne()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#findOne%28%29-detail)**

> Returns a single active record model instance by a primary key or an
>   array of column values.

```
$data = User::findOne(['userType' => 'AHP', 'userid' => $id]);
```

This will find the user whose `user type is AHP` and whose `userid is $id`.

```
public function getUser($id)
{
  $data = User::findOne(['userType' => 'AHP', 'userid' => $id]);
  return $data['AHPName'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

using custom queries:

```
public function getUser($id)
{

     $sql = "Select * from User where userType = 'AHP' and userid = '.$id.'";

     $return = User::findBySQL($sql)->one();

     return $return->AHPName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this technique for writing a custom query in yii2

```
  <?php
    use yii\db\Query;

    $query  = new Query(); 
    $query->select(['*'])->from('user')
                          ->where('user.userType=:id',['id'=>'AHP'])
                          ->andWhere('user.userid=:no',['no'=>$id]);


     $command   = $query->createCommand();
     $result    = $command->queryAll(); 
    ?>
```

another to do this

```
User::find()->where('userType = :type and userid = :id', 
            ['type'=>AHP, 'id' => $id])->one();
```